# For some reason the COALESE returns 0 instead of the correct value

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite, cordova

I am currently building a PhoneGap / Cordova application which uses SQLite

```
function screenONEpress(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql(   

    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PILE (word, frequency) 
     VALUES ( ?,   COALESCE( (SELECT frequency FROM PILE WHERE word = ?), 0) + 1  )",

                [screen1targetword] , errorcode

                        );
}
```

The table named PILE has columns titled Word, Meaning, and Frequency.

It does find the right value.  If I display all values of the table and I see no duplicate values.  However, for some reason, when running the SQL statement above, the frequency always becomes 1, meaning,

```
SELECT frequency FROM PILE WHERE word = ?
```

returned zero.

Comment: you are providing **two** placeholders (?) in your insert stmt. Should'nt you be providing two **separate** values for them? i.e `[screen1targetword,screen1targetword]`. Assuming that you want `screen1targetword` in both the places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by frank, you have two parameters, and give only one value, so the second one is always NULL.

Either give two parameter values:

```
tx.executeSql("... ? ... ? ...",
              [screen1targetword, screen1targetword], ...);
```

or use the [same parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) in both places:

```
tx.executeSql("... ?1 ... ?1 ...",
              [screen1targetword], ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you write the query like this?

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PILE (word, frequency) 
     SELECT ?,  COALESCE(MAX(frequency), 0) + 1, [screen1targetword] , errorcode
     FROM pile
     WHERE word = ?;
```

This should be the same logic, but you can directly test the `select` to be sure it is returning the correct value.